# Introduction into interrupted time series (intervention analyses for time series)

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis

I am looking for a good introduction into or an overview about [interrupted time series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupted_time_series) or intervention analyses for time series. Perhaps also considering [change point detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection) or [event study analyses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_study).

[This questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184713/resources-for-interrupted-time-series-analysis-in-r) deals with literature regarding R implementations but I am looking for a more general treatment (including theoretical considerations). I furthermore could not find the topic discussed in the literature outlined in that question ([Rob Hyndman](https://www.otexts.org/fpp), for example, discuss interventions only very briefly in a subchapter and I couldn't find it in [Shumway and Stoffer](https://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa4/tsa4.pdf)). Here is an interesting [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/225150/9866) outlining one specific approach how to deal with that topic.

Furthermore, is there a widely understood terminology for this kind of analyses? It seems for me that each field gives these statistical approaches different names.

Answer (score 1):

In general , the topic is Intervention Modelling . If you don't precisely know the date and the type of intervention this is referred to as Intervention Detection where a carefully launched search process is implemented to identify the date and type of intervention. Some limited implementations of this require " THE FORM OF THE ARIMA MODEL" to be pre-specified , others are much more general insofar as they simultaneously determine the arima model and the date and type.

An example of having to pre-specify the arima model form (with possible unintended consequences) is here https://www.r-bloggers.com/outliers-detection-and-intervention-analysis.

A seminal article is here http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html leading to https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf and https://autobox.com/pdfs/SARMAX.pdf . Early work assumed the date and form of the intervention which of course may be productive or counter-productive based upon the actual data.